# Line differences with element location in shell script

Tags: shell, text-files, element, tracking

Input:

file1.txt

```
abc 1 2 3 4
```

file2.txt

```
abc 1 2 5 6
```

Expected output:

```
differences is 
3 
5
at location 3
```

I am able to track the differences using:

```
comm -3 file1.txt file2.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $4}' | uniq
```

But not able to **track the element location**.

Could you guys please suggest the shell script to track the element location?

Comment: Why is that "location 3"? It's neither the third field nor the third character. If you want to know which byte of the file the first difference is at, you can use the `cmp` command.

Answer (score 0):

With perl, and Path::Class from CPAN for convenience

```
perl -MPath::Class -MList::Util=first -e '
    @f1 = split " ", file(shift)->slurp;
    @f2 = split " ", file(shift)->slurp;
    $idx = first {$f1[$_] ne $f2[$_]} 0..$#f1;
    printf "difference is\n%s\n%s\nat index %d\n", $f1[$idx], $f2[$idx], $idx;
' file{1,2}.txt
```

```
difference is
3
5
at index 3
```